# Header not show after update to magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, header

I had Magento 2.0.7 installation and my site worked fine.

Then recently I updated my site to Magento 2.1.0 and header section on my site is not visible now

What could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check you logs because if there will be any error in you less file, then `$block->renderFileLessToCss()` through error in header.phtml and Header stops working.

So check on var/log/system.log and correct your less file. That will resolved your issue.

Comment: It is also worth checking permissions on the var/pub folder if you are in developer mode. No write permission on the appropriate static css folder can give the same issue. This appears in the system.log too.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue after upgrading from 2.0.4 to 2.1.0 but then only some of the header content was not showing.

After few hours of debugging I realised that some of the references in out theme xml files was not working because Magento core team changed the name of `header.panel` container to `header.panel.wrapper` so we needed to modify our theme with the new name

Check [default.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.4/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L34) in 2.0.4 and find

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel" ... >
```

And then [default.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.0/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L34) in 2.1.0

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" ... >
```

I am not sure in which version this change is added and why but I compared directly 2.0.4 and 2.1.0 and notice it.